# Custom Layout for Dialog across different versions?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a Dialog with a custom layout (very simple). I set it up using the code below:

```
public static Dialog createGPSDialog(final Activity activity, boolean isLocationEnabled) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_Dialog);

    LinearLayout contentView = (LinearLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_twobutton, null);

    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    return dialog;
}
```

There's some code I omitted, but it isn't relevant. Anyway, this is how it looks in gingerbread:

[image: gingerbread]

and this is how it looks on jellybean (probably ics as well):

[image: jellybean]

The title area for the dialog is kept on JB, even after setting ContentView. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you can create new XML file in `res/values-v17`, which contains `Theme_Sherlock_Light_Dialog` and hides the title area. I think there are some attributes, perhaps…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be completely custom and get rid of the title bar, try adding this line to your code:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is defining a theme for your dialog. The constructor for Dialog takes a theme resources id. Just use one of android's android.R.theme.xxx.

When using the AlertDialog.Builder you can define a new theme using the contextthemewrapper.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html